# How is this casting happening in the following java code

Tags: java, inheritance, casting, downcast, upcasting

I do not understand how the casting is done on var2
The following line does not Compile as methodA1() not present in interface reference I1

```
String var = i1.methodA1();
```

Hence I1 requires a cast to invoke methodA1
I do not understand how the casting is done as A1 is not the child class of I1.
Child c = (Child)p; According to the syntax of downcasting A1 should be the Child class and i1 should be the parent object but neither is A1 the child class nor is i1 it's parent object
I also do not understand how I am able to call to call toString() from i1 and i2 because toString() is defined in class A1 and toString() is not declared in I1 and I2.

```
interface I1 {
    void methodI1(); //public static by default
}

interface I2 extends I1 {
    void methodI2(); //public static by default
}

class A1 {

    public String methodA1() {
        String strA1 = "I am in methodC1 of class A1";
        return strA1;
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        return "toString() method of class A1";
    }
}

class B1 extends A1 implements I2 {
    public void methodI1() {
        System.out.println("I am in methodI1 of class B1");
    }
    public void methodI2() {
        System.out.println("I am in methodI2 of class B1");
    }
}

public class InterFaceEx {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        I1 i1 = new B1();
        I2 i2 = new B1();
        String var2 = ((A1) i1).methodA1();// I1 requires a cast to invoke methodA1. How is this casting happening?
        System.out.println("var2 : " + var2);
        String var4 = i1.toString();// How I am able to call toString()?
        System.out.println("var4 : " + var4);
        String var5 = i2.toString();// How I am able to call toString()?
        System.out.println("var5 : " + var5);
    }
}
```

Comment: The first cast is because you have declared `i1` to be of type `I1`, and that is not any type of `A1`.  If you declared it as its actual type `B1` you wouldn't need to cast.

Comment: A1 is not the child class of I1 so how I am able to do this cast

Comment: Weak title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: There is no synatx error. I am unable to understand how the casting is done.

Comment: You can call any of `Object`'s methods via an interface reference, `toString()` included, because Java knows that every class extends `Object`.

Comment: toString() is a user defined method in class A1. So how can I call it with i1 and i2.

Comment: Because `A1.toString` is an override of `Object.toString`.

Comment: How am I able to cast i1 to A1 as A1 is not the child of I1

Comment: You can cast `i1` to `A1` because `i1` happens to reference an object of the class `B1` that implements `I1` **and** extends `A1`

Comment: Child c = (Child)p; According to the syntax of downcasting A1 should be the Child class and i1 should be the parent object but neither is A1 the child class nor is i1 it's parent object

Comment: Well, as you correctly noticed, `(A1) i1` is not a "downcast", but the compiler still allows it: [JLS-5.5.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5.1): _the cast is always legal at compile time (because even if T does not implement S, a subclass of T might)_. Call this "sidecasting" if that helps you understand it better.

Comment: How am I able to call toString() from i1 and i2 because toString() is defined in class A1 and toString() is not declared in I1 and I2.

Comment: Did you read the four linked questions? Your questions are covered in those links, please read them.